# Brightness issues on i3

Tags: sudo, brightness, i3-wm

I'm facing this issue on ubuntu 20.10 with i3 window manager: in i3 I found this workaround to change the screen brightness with a little .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter brightness: "
read brightness
echo "$brightness" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

The problem is that it requires sudo, and it doesen't fix changing the sudoers.d file or with sudo visudo, so the only way to avoid using sudo every time is by giving this command:

```
sudo chown username:username /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

and then it works fine without sudo. But every time i boot my system the brightness file's ownership goes back to root. Is there a way I can allways maintain this change?

I tried other solutions for controlling brightness in i3, such as xbacklight or light, but the first doesen't work at all, while with light i have the same sudo problem.

Comment: Two different approaches here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625144

Comment: Thank you @Quasímodo, the br.c script is working perfectly and integrates with i3 keybindings with no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ybacklight`

```
git clone https://github.com/szekelyszilv/ybacklight

cd ybackight

mkdir build; meson build; cd build; ninja install

ybacklight -get 

sudo ybacklight -set 20
```

Also, you can modify your sudoers file to run `ybacklight` without `sudo`:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt